# Running a second search against the results of the first

Tags: sphinx

Here's the scenario:

I have an indexed database table with over a half-million records.

Search #1 is run against this table to generate the, say, 20 best matches, which are then ordered descending according to relevance.

Search #2 needs to be run against only these results.  This search may, or may not, be the exact same query as Search #1.  Regardless, it needs to create a second, independent, set of weights against the results of Search #1.

Any pointers or suggestions on how to go about implementing something like this?

Not asking for someone to write me a solution - tips on what methods and objects to look at would be significantly helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do

```
... WHERE id IN ({list of ids from q1})
```

in sphinxQL for your second query.